# Basic Java Question, Classes updating GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

I will try and illustrate my question with examples, I am attempting to create a Java program that will (eventually) incorporate a complex Swing GUI.

I have Main.java

```
public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JTextArea example;

    public Main()
    {

    //... Missing, basic swing code
       example = new JTextArea();
    //... example added to jpanel, jpanel added to jframe, jframe set visible etc.


    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


    if(e.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase("Do Something!"))
    {
       new DoSomething();
    }

   public static void main(String[] args)  {

   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
     new Main();
      }
    });

}
```

}

So now, I want my DoSomething() class to update my example JTextArea, what is the best way to do this?

I can pass a reference to example to DoSomething(), so DoSomething(example), but that doesn't seem nice. I could also pass "this" to DoSomething() and implement a updateExample(String newString) method in Main but that doesn't seem great either.

Basically, what is the best way to achieve what I want to do? The program I am writing will ultimately get much more complicated than this and I can't see a way that will allow me to do this without it getting too messy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're looking for [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

I wrapped up a small example using your words

```
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;


public class Main implements Observer {
    private DoSomething businessClass;

    public Main() {
        businessClass = new DoSomething();
        businessClass.addObserver(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable obs, Object obj) {
        // Do whatever you want to do with textarea or other UI components
    }
}

class DoSomething extends Observable {
    public DoSomething() {
        Object result = new Object();    // It can be any type not just an object
        // After finish...
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(result);
    }
}
```

By using this small pattern the UI can be always aware of the status of your DoSomething class, and that class just need to invoke `notifyObservers` method. Thus your system keeps decoupled while being robust

Comment: After playing around with this I found that the observer would not be updated unless I called setChanged(); before notifyObservers();